# Is this criterion for sequence convergence true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I am studying sequences in $\mathbb{R}$.   I would like to know if a sequence satisfies that
"For all $n \in \mathbb{N}, |a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{3^{n}}$" then sequence $\left\{a_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent is true. I have looked for lots of examples and I have the same conditions for convergent sequences. Any counterexample?

Comment: $\sum |a_{n+1}-a_n| <\infty$ implies that $(a_n)$ converges. This has appeared any number of times on MSE.

Comment: Please do not  make changes to hypothesis after answers have appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.

A counterexample is $a_n=\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 1):

Another classic counterexample is the [Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Notice that the OP changed the question after our answers, and we are not notified of such changes.